# How do you write over an echoed line in php?

Tags: php, string, line, echo, command-line-interface

how can i write over an echoed line in php? For example lets say i have a for loop like this

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {

  echo $message .= ".";

}
```

i want to echo over `"........."`, how can i do it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "echo over"? Can you give an example of the output you want to produce?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Just `echo` the right thing in the first place?

Comment: Okay I think I get it, you want to do some kind of curses for the CLI? If so, @arnaud has the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Echo `\r` to move the cursor to the start of the line.

```
echo ".....";
echo "\r";
echo "123  ";
```

Will print "123" on the screen (command line, not in a browser, obviously).

Comment: Ah, indeed, that's why it didn't make sense in my head.